# value of SID passed via get

Tags: php, session, sid

I'm trying to pass the value of session id via get (url) and not via cookies.
My configuration of php.ini is:

session.use_cookies = on
session.use_only_cookies = off
session.use_trans_sid = on

Normally (always) the cookie are ENABLED in the user's browser, so if i try to pass the sid via url:
www.site.com/?phpsessid=abc
it doesn't work, because the constant SID (http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) remain empty and the session work with $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'].

If the cookie are manually DISABLED the session work with SID.

My question is: can i use the SID via get with cookies enabled? Maybe there is some php.ini configurations that i unknow....

thx :)

Answer (score -1):

It will be in `$_GET` or `$_COOKIES`. You could use `$_REQUEST['PHPSESSID']` to always get it.

But why do you need it? If you are using sessions, you pass your data around in in `$_SESSION`, and don't worry about the session id.

Comment: i'm trying to study session fixation and if in the user's browser the cookies are enable, the SID passed via get is ignored.
www.site.com/?phpsessid=abc
echo $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] = 'abc'
echo SID = empty!

Comment: @D. Milito, If you pass in the session id manually bad things can happen. Don't do this. Let php handle whether cookies are enabled. Call `session_start()`, then check $_GET and $_COOKIES to see what they contain. If there is no session id in get or cookies, you are doing something else wrong.  Don't ever try to set the session id yourself. A tool like firebug can help you see the raw request to check if a cookie header or url parameter is sent.

Comment: You have to call the session ID if you're passing the sessions between pages using the header() function. Take a look at the last note here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php